# Python - Creating bad zip files with ZipFile

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

My script is downloading files from URLs located in a text file, saving them temporarily to a given location, and then adding them to an already existing zip file in the same directory. The files are being downloaded successfully, and no errors are raised when adding to the zip files, but for some reason, most of the resulting zip files are un-openable by the OS, and when I `z.printdir()` on them, they do not contain all the expected files.

relevant code:

```
for root, dirs, files in 
os.walk(os.path.join(downloadsdir,dir_dictionary['content']), False):
if "artifacts" in root:
    solution_name = root.split('/')[-2]
    with open(os.path.join(root,'non-local-files.txt')) as file:
        for line in file:
            if "string" in line:
                print('\tDownloading ' + urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(line.rstrip())))
                file_name = urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(line.rstrip())).split('/')[-1]
                r = requests.get(urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(line.rstrip())))
                with open(os.path.join(root,file_name), 'wb') as temp_file:
                    temp_file.write(r.content)
                z = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, solution_name + '.zip'), 'a')
                z.write(os.path.join(root,file_name), os.path.join('Dropoff', file_name))
```

I guess my question is: am I doing something inherently wrong in the code, or do I have to look at the actual files being added to the zip files? The files are all OS-readable and appear normal as far as I can tell. Kind of at a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for root, dirs, files in 
os.walk(os.path.join(downloadsdir,dir_dictionary['content']), False):
if "artifacts" in root:
    solution_name = root.split('/')[-2]
    with open(os.path.join(root,'non-local-files.txt')) as file:
        for line in file:
            if "string" in line:
                print('\tDownloading ' + urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(line.rstrip())))
                file_name = urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(line.rstrip())).split('/')[-1]
                r = requests.get(urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(line.rstrip())))
                with open(os.path.join(root,file_name), 'wb') as temp_file:
                    temp_file.write(r.content)
                z = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, solution_name + '.zip'), 'a')
                try:
                    z.write(os.path.join(root,file_name), os.path.join('Dropoff', file_name))
                finally:
                    z.close()
```

PS:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html

Note

Archive names should be relative to the archive root, that is, they should not start with a path separator.

here is no official file name encoding for ZIP files. If you have unicode file names, you must convert them to byte strings in your desired encoding before passing them to write(). WinZip interprets all file names as encoded in CP437, also known as DOS Latin.

Comment: The problem was I wasn't closing the file prior to opening it for reading again. Zip files that were only written to one time were working fine.